# how to orderBy in laravel relationship using join

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have a query that has 2 problems for me .

1. i want to sort my model by its relationship fields
2. my `orderby` not working after using the `groupby` in my join .
   so here is my query :

```
$bill = Bill::with(['relation1', 'relation2'])
            ->where('category_id', $category)
            ->where('status_id', 2)
            ->join('funds','bills.id','=','funds.bill_id')
            ->select('bills.*','funds.*','funds.created_at as funds_created_at')
            ->groupBy('bills.id','funds.id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('bills.boosted', 'asc'))
            ->take(8)
            ->get();
        dd($bill);
```

so what i want to do here is to sort the bills by the boosted ones in the first place and if they are false which means not boosted sort them by the ones who got the last funds on it . 
Here my `orderby` is not working .

Comment: `SELECT *` is generally incompatible with `GROUP BY`.  Why are you using `GROUP BY` without selecting any aggregate functions?

Comment: i want to groupby to remove similar bills to show only one from each .

Comment: You must remove the asterisk and add proper expression with aggregate function for each output field not listed in GROUP BY expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in your orderBy clause:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('bills.boosted', 'asc'))
```

the method DB::raw doesn't take a second parameter.

you should use:

```
->orderByRaw('bills.boosted ASC')
```

or:

```
->orderBy('bills.boosted', 'asc')
```

more details about orderByRaw:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the strict of mysql config in `database.php` to:

```
'strict' => false
```

Also change the orderBy clause to:

```
->orderByRaw('`bills`.`boosted` asc')
```